# rust-bindgen bindings raise SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, rust, bindgen

I generated bindings to [Microsoft SEAL C++ Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/SEAL) using the [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen) tool.

My config:

```rust
// Generate the bindings
let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default()
    .generate_inline_functions(true)
    .derive_default(true)
    .header("./seal/src/seal/seal.h")
    .clang_arg("-I./seal/src/")
    .clang_arg("-std=c++17")
    .clang_arg("-x")
    .clang_arg("c++")
    .opaque_type("std::.*")
    .whitelist_type("seal::.*")
    .whitelist_function("seal::.*")
    .generate()
    .expect("Unable to generate bindings");
```

The SEAL project is compiled using [cc-rs](https://github.com/alexcrichton/cc-rs) using this config:

```rust
let mut build = cc::Build::new();                
    build.cpp(true);                                 
    build.flag_if_supported("-std=c++17");           
    build.flag_if_supported("-march=native");        
    build.flag_if_supported("-fkeep-inline-functions");                                                   
    build.flag_if_supported("-fno-inline-functions");
    let base_path = Path::new("./seal/src/seal/");   
    let util_base_path = Path::new("./seal/src/seal/util/");                                              
    add_cpp_files(&mut build, base_path);            
    add_cpp_files(&mut build, util_base_path);       
    build.include("./seal/src");                     
    build.compile("seal");
```

But afterwards, when creating a new context (this is mostly SEAL-specific) using a **static** method I get a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV: invalid reference) which, I figured after debugging with `gdb` comes from when a pointer to a memory pool is copied.

I was able to instantiate multiple regular objects (stuff that didn't have a static constructor) but it doesn't seem to work for SEALContext no matter what parameters I try.

You can access my project [seal-rs here](https://github.com/Belval/seal-rs). The whole thing is in the build script and clones the repo so `cargo test` should build and reproduce the error.

My OS is Archlinux 64bit, the compiler used is clang 7.

Comment: Question should self include everything to answer the question, a link to github is not enough. If you can't include it because it's too big your question is too broad, work on a [mcve].

Comment: I don't expect anyone to actually build the thing. I thought someone with bindgen experience would be able to tell me if I'm missing a flag. I'll see to it.

Comment: bindgen is not fully compatible with C++, also note that bindgen do "the best guest", there is a lot of thing not specify in the C or C++ standard, so a lot of thing could be wrong.

Comment: The layout test might fail but the library compiles. You can generate the bindings without layout tests by passing the proper flag.

Comment: The auto-generated tests all passes. It's a custom test that uses the bindings that fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in the rust-bindgen library as such I will close the question.